# Pass a List from HTML Razor View via Form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

This is My Tennant Class which have list of Contact Person

```
public class Tennant
    {
        public Tennant()
        {
            ContactPerson = new List<HR.ContactPerson>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }

        public List<ContactPerson> ContactPerson { get; set; }

    }
```

and this is Contact Person Class

```
  public class ContactPerson
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public long CNIC { get; set; }
        public DateTime CNICExpiry { get; set; }
        public long MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

I am Unable to understand how create view (form) for list

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CompanyName, new { })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "CompanyName", placeholder = "Enter Company Name", type = "text" })
                <small id="companyName" class="form-text text-muted">Use M/S first.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BrandName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BrandName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "BrandName", placeholder = "Enter Brand Name", type = "text" })
                <small id="brandName" class="form-text text-muted">Full Product / Brand Name</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.OfficeAddress)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OfficeAddress, new { @class = "form-control", id = "OfficeAddress", placeholder = "Enter Office Address", type = "text" })
                <small id="officeAddress" class="form-text text-muted">Full Office Address.</small>
            </div>
```

unable to Understand how manage Contact Person List

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ContactPerson.)
```

what should I Do?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `for`-loop and then the default model-binder will work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ContactPerson.Count; ++i)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ContactPerson[i].FirstName)
}
```

Note: You need to add an "empty" `ContactPerson` instances into the list to get input fields for a new person.